# Translations for HTML Areas

Tags: customer-portal, html, translation

I have an HTML area and Custom HTML Header / Footer in a customer portal.
The portal is being converted to be multi-lingual.

Does anyone know of a way to enter translations for HTML areas?

If this can't be done declaritively within Salesforce, what's your approach for coding this?

Answer (score 7):

One way to do this is use custom labels to store all your text .And enable translation workbench.

https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_wbench.htm

The portal will be automatically changed to the language as per the locale of the user and the translation of labels will display .

At run time if you want to change the language of the portal as per user input or choice you can use langauge attribute of apex:page

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_page.htm

```
<apex:page sidebar="true" showHeader="false" language="ru">
```

The language parameter of the page decides language.

Make a getter setter variable in the controller and use userinfo to get the language or through the query and populate on the language parameter.